# Errors in Xcode using SDL

Tags: sdl, c, xcode

I am using Lazy Foo's Production tutorials for making an SDL game in C in Xcode 6.1 - http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php#Hello%20SDL. I'm using Xcode 7 but I don't think they are very different.

In the second tutorial (http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php).
I cannot seem to compile properly without an error regarding one of the functions.

The function prototype:

```
//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();
```

Then the function declaration:

```
void close()
{
    //Deallocate surface
    SDL_FreeSurface( gHelloWorld );
    gHelloWorld = NULL;

    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

And then the function call at the end:

```
close();
```

I am getting these errors and am not quite sure how to fix them. Other solutions online are for problems that are not quite the same as mine.

`SDL_Tutorial/SDL_Tutorial/using_image.c:28:6: Conflicting types for 'close'`

`SDL_Tutorial/SDL_Tutorial/using_image.c:28:6: Conflicting types for 'close'`

`SDL_Tutorial/SDL_Tutorial/using_image.c:127:5: Implicit declaration of function 'close' is invalid in C99`

`SDL_Tutorial/SDL_Tutorial/using_image.c:127:11: Too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0`

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am struggling to make progress with learning SDL game programming at the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry if question is irrelevant, I'm not familiar with tutorial. You are using C with procedure programming, there is no OOP, right?
Is your `close()` function has overloaded version with different amount is parameters? Is it declared in the same file from which is get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lazyfoo tutorials don't have the best coding practices. I can see two problems:

- `close` is too generic of a name for a function. It's most likely conflicting with an [existing function with the same signature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/close.html). You should rename the function.
- In C, `void foo()` is not the right way to declare "a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing". It's `void foo(void)`. You should either fix the declaration, or compile your code as C++, as lazyfoo assumes (note that if you download their code their files are inside `.cpp` files). In C++ `void foo()` is a correct declaration.

Comment: Sorry I've replied a bit late, I've been quite busy. I've done what you said: I changed `void close()` to `void close_game(void)` and I'm glad to say those errors are gone, so thank you very much for that. However, I am still getting the error `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: You should google that error message to see if there's anything helpful. If that doesn't help, ask a new question.

Comment: @kashveyron, call up the build log in Xcode. If you hover your mouse arrow over the right end of the error message's line, there will be a little "three lines of text" icon button. Click that to see the full compiler output for the error message. That should include a list of the functions or globals (symbols) that the linker is missing.

Comment: Ok I've done that and it seems the main error is `3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`. I have identified the 'duplicate symbols' as `_main`, `_SCREEN_HEIGHT` and `_SCREEN_WIDTH`. Then under each of them, it names the files that I am working on and the directory in which they are found. But I don't know anything more than that in terms of what 'duplicate symbols' actually means.

Comment: Sorry, I'm late, you may have solved your problem already, but if someone else ends up here: "symbol" is a catch-all term for a function, global variable, or const global variable, basically. Ignore the leading underscore in this case, that's a technical detail of the compiler. So it is saying that you have 3 copies of your `main()` function and your `SCREEN_HEIGHT` and `SCREEN_WIDTH` constants. Look in your project's "compile sources" build phase, you may have accidentally caused the `.cpp` source file end up there 3 times.

Comment: Alernately, it could be that you wrote something in the header instead of in the implementation files. Every file that includes a header gets its own copy of whatever is in it. If the header just contains class declarations or function prototypes, that's fine, but if you actually put definitions of globals (i.e. a global with an initial value) or functions into it, then there will be duplicates.